# Creating my on split method that includes delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to create my own split method that includes the delimiters in the output.  I have this code so far:

```
private static String[] split(String string, String regex) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    String leftovers = string;

    if (regex.charAt(0) != '[' && regex.charAt(regex.length() - 1) != ']') {
        int i = 0;
        while (!leftovers.isEmpty()) {
            if (i == leftovers.indexOf(regex)) {
                if (!leftovers.substring(0, leftovers.indexOf(regex)).isEmpty()) {
                    output.add(leftovers.substring(0, leftovers.indexOf(regex)));
                }
                output.add(regex);
                leftovers = leftovers.substring(i + regex.length());
                i = 0;
            } else if (leftovers.indexOf(regex) == -1) {
                output.add(leftovers);
                leftovers = "";
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        char[] regexChars = new char[regex.length() - 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < regexChars.length; i++) {
            regexChars[i] = regex.charAt(i + 1);
        }

        int i = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < regexChars.length; j++) {
            while (!leftovers.isEmpty()) {


                if (i == leftovers.indexOf(regexChars[j])) {
                    if (!leftovers.substring(0, leftovers.indexOf(regexChars[j])).isEmpty()) {
                        output.add(leftovers.substring(0, leftovers.indexOf(regexChars[j])));
                    }
                    output.add(Character.toString(regexChars[j]));
                    leftovers = leftovers.substring(i + 1);
                    i = 0;
                } else if (leftovers.indexOf(regexChars[j]) == -1) {
                    output.add(leftovers);
                    leftovers = "";
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output.toArray(new String[0]);

}
```

The input arguments I am trying to pass in are "a?b?gf#e" and "[?#]".  However, the output I get is `[a, ?, b, ?, gf, null, e]`.  If I reverse the delimiters in regex as "[#?]", I get `[a, a?b?gf#e]`
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  FYI I don't want to use the Pattern and Matcher classes, and we are not allowed to use the built-in split method at all.

Comment: Why are you creating your own split method?

Comment: The Guava splitter class is excellent btw

Comment: `split` uses regex so why not just use a zero width assertion, i.e. a lookaround to define your delimiter?

Comment: @RohitJain Our reasons for custom split was absent in Java 1.3 in ebemdded devices.

Comment: Can your please give an example what do you expect as correct output ???

Comment: Correct output would be `[a, ?, b, ?, gf, #, e]`, regardless of the order of delimiters in regex.

Comment: I don't know java but every other implementation of split using regex allows you to include the delimeter in the array output as long as capture parenthesis are around it. I.e.:  `split("([?#])")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are creating your own `split()` method. You should rather build a regex that will return the delimiters as separate array elements. Use that regex with the existing `split()` method. It would work well.

If you want to split on delimiter - `[?#]`, while keeping the delimiters as separate array entry, then split on the **empty string** preceded and followed by those delimiters. That will do the job:

```
String str = "a?b?gf#e";        
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=[?#])|(?=[?#])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));  // [a, ?, b, ?, gf, #, e]
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[?#])   // Empty String preceded by `[?#]`
   |        // OR
(?=[?#])    // Empty String followed by `[?#]`
```

Comment: FYI, this is for a homework assignment, where we are required to create our own split that includes delimiters.

Comment: @PinkJazz They told you to build your own `split()` method for this task?

Comment: Yes, we have to build our own split method.

Comment: @PinkJazz For home work I am sure you are not allowed to use regex spliting, so implement it yourself, by checking each chararacter to be on eof your delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It works pretty good  It will ignore anything that is not part of the split. hope this helps man. If you have any questions let me know.

```
public static String[] split(String str, String regex)
    {
        Vector<String> result = new Vector<String>();

    int start = 0;
    int pos = str.indexOf(regex);
    char[] charArray = new char[regex.length()];;

    if(regex.length() > 1){
        for(int i = 0; i< regex.length();i++){
            charArray[i] = regex.charAt(i);
        }
        for(char chars:charArray){
            {
                pos = str.indexOf(Character.toString(chars));
                while (pos>=start) {
                    if (pos>start) {
                        result.add(str.substring(start,pos));
                    }
                    start = pos + 1;
                    result.add(Character.toString(chars));
                    pos = str.indexOf(Character.toString(chars),start); 
                    System.out.println(pos);
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        while (pos>=start) {
            if (pos>start) {
                result.add(str.substring(start,pos));
            }
            start = pos + regex.length();
            result.add(regex);
            pos = str.indexOf(regex,start); 
        }
        if (start<str.length()) {
            result.add(str.substring(start));
        }
    }
    String[] array = result.toArray(new String[0]);
    return array;
}
}
```